# How replace character next to numeric but not next to alphanumeric in R

Tags: r, text-mining, stringr

I have this string

```
char <- "866224; Genoma viral SARS-CoV-2: Detectable; 1096628; Genoma viral SARS-CoV-2: No detectable"
```

and I need replace ; next to numbers with | but keep ; next to alphanumeric like this:

```
"866224| Genoma viral SARS-CoV-2: Detectable; 1096628| Genoma viral SARS-CoV-2: No detectable"
```

I was trying with str_replace_all

```
str_replace_all(char, "[0-9];", "|")
```

but remove the last number.

```
"86622| Genoma viral SARS-CoV-2: Detectable; 109662| Genoma viral SARS-CoV-2: No detectable"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Removes last digits too.

Comment: In base R : `gsub('([0-9]);', '\\1|', char)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `{stringr}` package allows for lookaheads and lookbehinds you could use them instead of actually capturing the last number then pasting it:

```r
char <- "866224; Genoma viral SARS-CoV-2: Detectable; 1096628; Genoma viral SARS-CoV-2: No detectable"
str_replace_all(char, "(?<=[0-9]);", "|")
#> [1] "866224| Genoma viral SARS-CoV-2: Detectable; 1096628| Genoma viral SARS-CoV-2: No detectable"
```

the lookbehind `(?<=...)` basically checks if the expression that follows is preceded by `...`.
if you want to use this in `baseR` then:

```
gsub("(?<=[0-9]);", "|", char, perl=TRUE)
#> [1] "866224| Genoma viral SARS-CoV-2: Detectable; 1096628| Genoma viral SARS-CoV-2: No detectable"
```

Answer (score 3):

In your example, you replace the number *and* the semicolon by `|`. Instead, you can capture the number with parentheses and replace it in your expression with `\\1`:

```
library(stringr)

char <- "866224; Genoma viral SARS-CoV-2: Detectable; 1096628; Genoma viral SARS-CoV-2: No detectable"

str_replace_all(char, "([0-9]);", "\\1|")
#> [1] "866224| Genoma viral SARS-CoV-2: Detectable; 1096628| Genoma viral SARS-CoV-2: No detectable"
```